# Copy a selection from a worksheet to new workbook, values/number format, save as tab delimited .txt to specific location, close new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

As the title states. I am attempting to automate this process. The end result is, I email the text file to a static recipient. If that can be included great, if not, I have another macro to handle that simple task.

I can copy my desired selection (AM1:CK74) to a new workbook, but the rest if beyond me.

So, what I would like to do, from a command button, is Copy AM1:CK74 from the active sheet to a new workbook, paste in A1 as values and number format, save as tab delimited .txt, file name should be the values of cells B1&C1. then email this text file with Outlook.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've messed around with the auto-record function, but this is too specific for me.

```
    Sub DataPull3()
'
' DataPull3 Macro
'

'
    Range("AL1:CK74").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\##\Documents\Book10.txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Thank You.

Comment: **Post your current code.**

Comment: This just copies values and number formats. It was generated through the recorder with a little tweaking. In addition to this, I'd like to have the file name be referencing two cells in the worksheet. and then close the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
Sub Macro2()

     Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Range("AM1:CK74").Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\temp"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\Book3.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hi there"
  '      .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\temp\Book3.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I tweaked the paste to paste special values and formats, and it is almost perfect. if the file could be named on the values of B1 and C1 (date and location), then the newly created workbook closed, it would be perfect. Thanks Sathish!

Answer (score 1):

Through your generous assistance, I've solved my question. Please see the attached code for the changes I've made.

Thank You!.

```
Sub CopyDistribute()

     Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim relativePath As String, sname As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("AM1:CK74").Copy
    Workbooks.Add
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=relativePath & Range("A1") & Range("B1"), _
    FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

    sname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") & ".xls"
    relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & sname
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "EMAIL.com"
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = ""
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```